# SonarQube 6.3 LDAP/SSO UTF-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ldap, sonarqube, single-sign-on

We‘re using LDAP/SSO in my company which provides the username in UTF-8 format to SonarQube.

However LDAP/SSO sends the username in UFT-8 but SonarQube requires Latin1/ISO-8859. There is no way to change the encoding on LDAP/SSO or SonarQube.

Result wrong umlauts:

`Andrü Tingö` = `Andr«Ã Ting¼Ã OR äëüö = Ã¤Ã«Ã¼Ã`

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why do you say SonarQube is requiring Latin1/ISO-8859 ? UTF-8 is the encoding that should be used everywhere.

Comment: Hi @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam
Because the username, sent by LDAP/SSO, appears to SonarQube to be encoded in Latin1/ISO-8859, even though it actually is in UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, I'll then investigate and come back to you

Comment: Hum, just before I investigate, could you tell me how are you using LDAP with SSO ? Are  you using sonar.web.sso.enable ?

Comment: Yes, we are using sonar.web.sso.enable which is set to true.
For LDAP and SSO we are using simplesamlphp.

1) We have done some tests. We are 100% sure that our username(Andrü Tingö) from SSO is coming in UTF-8 and it's also forwarded as UTF-8 to Sonarqube.
2) SonarQube output: <h1 id="name" class="pull-left">Andr«Ã Ting¼Ã</h1> --> Therefore the string is converted to UFT-8 twice.

Comment: I've tested to authenticate into SonarQube using SSO with a user name "Andrü Tingö", and everyhing is fine, the name is correctly displayed.

Comment: Hi @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Have you seen Roberts input? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as comment, but I need 50 reputations to write comments.

We are using simplesamlphp for SSO as IdP and SP. IdP takes cn, givenName and sn from LDAP, which has UTF-8 values. Loginnames/Usernames are us-ascii only.

If the user comes to Sonar, the non-us-ascii characters are incorrect - they were converted from ... to utf-8, even they already are in utf-8.

If I use the attributes from IDP in PHP which sends the page in UTF-8, then characters are correct.

I did just now one test. In our Apache Config we set the X-Forwarded-Name to MCAC_ATTR_CN attribute what SP get from IdP. Original configuration is:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Name "expr=%{reqenv:MCAC_ATTR_CN}"
```

Now I have added fixed string in UTF-8:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Name "expr=%{reqenv:MCAC_ATTR_CN} cäëöüc"
```

The "c" characters are only separators to see the encoded text better.

The hexdump of this configuration line is:

```
0000750:        09 0909 5265 7175 6573 7448 6561     ...RequestHea
0000760: 6465 7220 7365 7420 582d 466f 7277 6172  der set X-Forwar
0000770: 6465 642d 4e61 6d65 2022 6578 7072 3d25  ded-Name "expr=%
0000780: 7b72 6571 656e 763a 4d43 4143 5f41 5454  {reqenv:MCAC_ATT
0000790: 525f 434e 7d20 63c3 a4c3 abc3 b6c3 bc63  R_CN} c........c
00007a0: 220a                                     ".
```

As you can see, there are fixed utf-8 characters "ä" c3a4 "ë" c3ab "ö" c3b6 "ü" c3bc.

From LDAP comes follwing name:

```
xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx äëüö
```

In Apache config is appended " cäëöüc", therefore resulting name should be:

```
xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx äëüö cäëöüc
```

But in Sonar, the name is displayed as

```
xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx Ã¤Ã«Ã¼Ã¶ cÃ¤Ã«Ã¶Ã¼c
```

You get similar result if you convert follwing text:

```
xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx äëüö cäëöüc
```

from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8:

```
echo "xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx äëüö cäëöüc" | iconv -f iso-8859-2 -t utf-8
xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx Ă¤ĂŤĂźĂś cĂ¤ĂŤĂśĂźc
```

The "¤" character is utf-8 char c2 a4:

```
00000000: c2a4 0a                                  ...
```

I have made tcpdump on loopback to get communications from apache proxy module to sonarqube and even there you can see correct UTF-8 characters c3a4 c3ab c3bc c3b6 comming from IdP and then between "c"s you can see c3a4 c3ab c3b6 c3bc comming direct from apache.

```
00000000  47 45 54 20 2f 61 63 63  6f 75 6e 74 20 48 54 54   GET /acc ount HTT
...
00000390  58 2d 46 6f 72 77 61 72  64 65 64 2d 4e 61 6d 65   X-Forwar ded-Name
000003A0  3a 20 72 6f 62 65 72 74  20 74 65 73 74 32 20 77   : xxxxxx  xxxxx x
000003B0  6f 6c 66 20 c3 a4 c3 ab  c3 bc c3 b6 20 63 c3 a4   xxx .... .... c..
000003C0  c3 ab c3 b6 c3 bc 63 0d  0a                        ......c. .       
...
```

The system has locales set to en_US.UTF-8, if this matters.

So Sonar gets really UTF-8 Text from Apache (direct config or from IdP) but then something probably converts this utf-8 text as if it was iso-8859 text to utf-8 again and makes nonsense.

Do you have any idea now? Could this be something in sonar or in wrapper or somewhere some options set incorrectly?

Regards,

Robert.